# Queue or event as a switch between processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a system formed by 3 processes: a main one, and 2 child processes.

The first child process is constantly checking for a condition, and once this condition is verified, something happens in the second child process.
This can happen multiple times.

So I was wondering...is it possible to use a mp.Event as trigger? I'm thinking of...switching it, like a True/False bool variable, and looking for it in the second process.
Something like this:

**main process**

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import set_start_method, Queue, Event
from p01 import P01_Initializer
from p02 import P02_Initializer
import time
import sys

def main():
    set_start_method("spawn")
    sw_event = mp.Event()

    p01 = mp.Process(target=P01_Initializer, args=(sw_event, ))
    p01.daemon = True
    p01.start()
    p02 = mp.Process(target=P01_Initializer, args=(sw_event, ))
    p02.daemon = True
    p02.start()

    ## close everything after 15 seconds
    t_start = time.time()
    while True:
        if time.time() - t_start > 15:
            p01.terminate()
            p02.terminate()
            sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**first child process**

```
import time

def P01_Initializer(sw_event):
    process_01 = P01(sw_event)
    process_01.run()

class P01():
    def __init__(self, sw_event):
        self.sw_event = sw_event

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if condition:
                self.sw_event.set() ### switching it, like a bool variable
```

**second child process**

```
import time

def P02_Initializer(sw_event):
    process_02 = P02(sw_event)
    process_02.run()

class P02():
    def __init__(self, sw_event):
        self.sw_event = sw_event

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.sw_event == False:
                do nothing
            else:
                self.sw_event.set() ### switch it back to False, waiting for next occurence
                do something
```

Is something like this possible, or should I just use a boolean variable and pass it between processes using a Queue?

Comment: In the second child process, you might want to check the event by `self.sw_event.is_set()` instead compare it with Boolean value.

Comment: That's almost getting the job done! Is there any way to...unset the event?

Comment: Just found there is, you can use sw_event.clear() :)

Comment: One alternative I use are flag files. You create an empty file somewhere in the first process and check its presence and/or clear it (=remove it) in another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so basically you can set/unset (?) the event by using:

```
sw_event.set()
sw_event.clear()
```

once you do that, you can check the status of the event by:

```
sw_event.is_set()
```